# Upload Unity App as replacement of android studio App on Market

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, sign

I want to migrate an android app to unity !
the question is how I can sign the apk that replace in the market as the next version of the app !
I did that with unity internal apk builder but the market response an error ! 
you have to use same sign !
is there any way to do that ?
best regards

Comment: You have to use your app market keystore file and the password to sign build your Unity project Did you do that?

Comment: @Programmer unity uses ".keystore" file but android studio use ".jks" file and I don't know how to sign unity app with ".jks" file !

Comment: silly suggestion, but did you try just changing extention?

Comment: @obywan thanks ! that worked.